# Check s3 objects and notify if they are in the bucket for more than 1 hour

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking to create a lambda which will constantly monitor my directory in the s3 bucket and will notify if the objects resides in the bucket for more than 1 hour after the upload. We already have a lambda to archive the object after processing which is invoked based on s3 events. But I need a function to calculate the time of the object and notify.

I tried something like this. Doesn't help.

```
import boto3
import datetime
s3=boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket=s3.Bucket('mybucketname')
def obj_age(s3):
    modified=s3.ObjectSummary('last_modified')
    return modified
    modified=obj_age(s3)
    if len(obj_age)==modified-datetime.timedelta(hours=1):
        return ["\nFound %i files more than %s hours old in %s." % (len(old_age), 1, bucket.name))]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Trigger a Lambda every hour to check the files in the bucket and see if 1 hour has past since their last modified time stamp - have you tried that? Or is that what you're asking help for?

Comment: And you just want the number of items? Or more information? You will have to paginate through the items in the bucket

Comment: What data do you exactly want?

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you already have a Lambda function to "process and archive" the file, so what are you wanting to check? Are you checking whether the first Lambda function worked successfully? What do you mean by "calculate the time of the object and notify"? Please Edit your question to add these details rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, I have a lambda to process and archive and its working. issue is that for some reason the lambda did not trigger last time. I need to notify be notified about this. like after every upload, if the files are untouched for an hour or so, I need to be notified that the files are staying in the directory for so long. So I am looking to create another lambda to monitor my bucket periodically and let know if the timestamp of the objects has not changed for more than an hour after upload. hope I am have given some additional information now.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes you are right, I want to create a Lambda that will monitor a directory in my S3 bucket every hour and check if the last modified time stamp is > 1 hour and it has to notify me that no changes was made on the object. I am looking for a Python code for this.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein basically what I am looking for is "I want to create a Lambda that will monitor a directory in my S3 bucket every hour and check if the last modified time stamp of the objects are < 1 hour. If last modified time stamp of the objects are > 1 hour it should notify that no changes was made to the object.

Comment: I would recommend that you investigate why your first Lambda function is not performing as desired. You say "for some reason the lambda did not trigger last time", but this is _highly_ unusual. Did you check the CloudWatch Logs file to see whether the Lambda function was triggered? Does your code in that first Lambda function loop through **all even records** rather than just looking at `event['Records'][0]`? Feel free to create a Question with full details so that we can assist you with that problem. Sorry to say, but your Python code above is not correct, the other function might be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To monitor your bucket you could:

- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that lists the contents of the bucket, looks for any object that is more than an hour old and sends a message to an **Amazon SNS Topic** with details of the object(s) found
- Subscribe to the SNS Topic to receive an email when a message is sent to the Topic
- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** to trigger the Lambda function once per hour

Here is an example Lambda function that will check for any objects more than an hour old, and send a message to an Amazon SNS Topic for any found:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import tzutc, UTC

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:Old-File-Warning'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
sns_resource = boto3.resource('sns')
sns_topic = sns_resource.Topic(TOPIC_ARN)

for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.all():
    if object.last_modified < datetime.now(tzutc()) - timedelta(hours = 1):
        message = f"Object {object.key} is more than 1 hour old!"
        sns_topic.publish(Message=message)
```

Of course, you should actually investigate the reason why your initial Lambda function is failing, which would be much simpler than writing and maintaining this 'check' function.

Comment: Thank you for the function. one question. How do I ask the function to monitor only a specific folder within the s3. I want it to check for the files only in "my-bucket/folder1/folder2/" I tried this. doesn`t help

```s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_prefix="prefix"
objs = BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix = bucket_prefix)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects' ```

Comment: `for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.filter(Prefix='folder1/folder2/'):`

Comment: I am getting this error
```{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: [ERROR] Runtime.HandlerNotFound: Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'

Comment: when I put like this  I get lambda test status: failed

```def handler_name(event, context):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    sns_resource = boto3.resource('sns')
    sns_topic = sns_resource.Topic(TOPIC_ARN)
    return 
    s3_resource
    sns_topic
    sns_resource```
[ERROR] NameError: name 's3_resource' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to understand your situation through these comments. I recommend that you create a new Question with full details of your situation.